# Error when creating procedure with existing query

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have a query that I am trying to use within a procedure. The query works exactly as it should but once I place it inside of the BEGIN and END of the procedure, it tells me "name is already used by an existing object". Not sure what this means, any help would be great.
Here is the orignal query:

```
SELECT
        course.course_no,
        course.description,
        section.section_no,
        enrcount.countofenrollment
    FROM
        course
        INNER JOIN section ON course.course_no = section.course_no
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT
                section_id,
                COUNT(*) countofenrollment
            FROM
                enrollment
            GROUP BY
                section_id
        ) enrcount ON section.section_id = enrcount.section_id
    WHERE
        enrcount.countofenrollment < 6;
```

Here is the procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PRC_Enrollment 
AS 
BEGIN
    SELECT
        course.course_no,
        course.description,
        section.section_no,
        enrcount.countofenrollment
    FROM
        course
        INNER JOIN section ON course.course_no = section.course_no
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT
                section_id,
                COUNT(*) countofenrollment
            FROM
                enrollment
            GROUP BY
                section_id
        ) enrcount ON section.section_id = enrcount.section_id
    WHERE
        enrcount.countofenrollment < 6;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `create or replace procedure..` instead of just `create procedure..` in order to resolve the error youve mentioned above. That means already the procedure name has been used.

Answer (score 0):

First of all `INTO` clause should be added to return the values of the columns

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PRC_Enrollment AS 
   v_course_no   course.course_no%type;
   v_description course.description%type;
   v_section_no  section.section_no%type;
   v_count_enrl  int;
BEGIN
  SELECT c.course_no, c.description, s.section_no, e.countofenrollment
    INTO v_course_no, v_description, v_section_no , v_count_enrl
    FROM course c
    JOIN section s
      ON c.course_no = s.course_no
    JOIN (SELECT section_id, COUNT(*) countofenrollment
            FROM enrollment
           GROUP BY section_id) e
      ON s.section_id = e.section_id
   WHERE e.countofenrollment < 6;
 EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN NULL;
END;
/
```

Alternatively you can return those values as out parameters by using

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PRC_Enrollment(
                                        v_course_no   out course.course_no%type,
                                        v_description out course.description%type,
                                        v_section_no  out section.section_no%type,
                                        v_count_enrl  out int
                                       ) AS
```

instead of returning them as local variables as in the first case.

- alias your tables with a letter, usually preferred the first letter
  of the tables
- add exception handling, at least against the case no data found in
  order not to get error

*Btw, **you get such an error**, if `OR REPLACE` has not been added after `CREATE` keyword for the second and subsequent compilations.*

Comment: Where you added the ... after FROM, are you implying it stays like that? Or would that just return to FROM course? Slightly confused. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I just didn't want to replicate all your query @cm1917 . Dots stand for the parts between FROM and the last WHERE. You're welcome.

Comment: Gotcha, that makes sense. I am getting this error: Error(4,27): PLS-00201: identifier 'ENRCOUNT.COUNTOFENROLLMENT' must be declared. Not sure what would have caused this

Comment: hm, I just fixed @cm1917 , noticed that is not a column of a table but an integer value returning from `count()` function. Btw use aliases for the tables within the query such as `c` for `course`, `s` for `section` .